# Find Existing Solutions for $\sin(x)\cos(x)=0$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

I've managed to understand how to get to $x = \pi$ and $x = \pi/2$, but I have no idea where to go from here or how to find the interval or quadrant. I'm kinda new to trigonometry so I'm very lost.

Comment: The product of two real numbers can only be zero if one of them is zero. Sketch the sine and cosine functions over the interval you are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $2\sin x\cos x=\sin(2x)$. So your question is the same as solving $\sin(2x)=0$ on $[0,2\pi]$, which is the same as solving $\sin z=0$ on $[0,4\pi]$. Once you find $z$, set $x=\frac{z}{2}$.

Comment: You mean $x = \frac z2$...

Comment: @Ak. ah, fixed. Thanks.